# Excel Azure SQL Server execute command error

Tags: sql, excel, azure-sql-database, ado

I can't seem to work out why my executing code is not working. Any help is appreciated. Datatypes are either int, nvarchar, or one column being datetime2. I have copied the connection string from my Azure portal

Cheers

```
Sub Upload_Data()
   

Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim sSQL As String

Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection

SQLSERVER_CONN_STRING = "Provider=SQLNCLI11;Server=tcp:myserver,1433;Initial Catalog=nzab_server;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=userid;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;"

oConn.Open SQLSERVER_CONN_STRING

oConn.Execute "INSERT INTO dbo.Database([Group],[Client],[Enterprise],[Shed],[Version_Name],[Version_Number],[Fiscal_Year],[Period],[Month],[Version_Period],[Client_Account_L1],[Client_Account_L2],[Client_Account_L3],[NZAB_Account_Group],[NZAB_Account],[Time],[Username],[Value],[Corrected_Value]) VALUES(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,16000101,1,1,1)"

MsgBox ("Data Uploaded")

If Not oConn Is Nothing Then
    If oConn.State = 1 Then oConn.Close
End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: Did you connect to Azure SQL database? The server name should be the whole name like `Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;`.

Comment: It errors out on the execute line, so can connect to the sql server. I didnt put in my server name (nor userid/password) for security reasons!